# How to add columns into org.apache.spark.sql.Row inside of mapPartitions

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am a newbie at scala and spark, please keep that in mind :)

Actually, I have three questions

1. How should I define function to pass it into df.rdd.mapPartitions, if I want to create new Row with few additional columns
2. How can I add few columns into Row object(or create a new one)
3. How create DataFrame from created RDD

Thank you at advance

Comment: May I ask why do you need this? Maybe some example code / input / output. It is possible, but usually there are a better ways.

Comment: Sure

I have two different sets of elements, one is huge(in form of dataframe) and another one is quite small, and i have find some min value between these two sets. My idea is that i put lesser set into some quite optimal structure, pass it into mapPartitions, calculate some values for each item and put them "near" to other values.

Comment: There there should be no need for `mapPartitions` .

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Usually there should be no need for that** and it is better to use UDFs but here you are:

> How should I define function to pass it into df.rdd.mapPartitions, if I want to create new Row with few additional columns

It should take `Iterator[Row]` and return `Iterator[T]` so in your case you should use something like this

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

def transformRows(iter: Iterator[Row]): Iterator[Row] = ???
```

> How can I add few columns into Row object(or create a new one)

There are multiple ways of accessing `Row` values including `Row.get*` methods, `Row.toSeq` etc. New `Row` can be created using `Row.apply`, `Row.fromSeq`, `Row.fromTuple` or `RowFactory`. For example:

```
def transformRow(row: Row): Row =  Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq ++ Array[Any](-1, 1))
```

> How create DataFrame from created RDD

If you have `RDD[Row]` you can use `SQLContext.createDataFrame` and provide schema.

Putting this all together:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{IntegerType, StructField, StructType}

val  df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    (1.0, 2.0), (0.0, -1.0),
    (3.0, 4.0), (6.0, -2.3))).toDF("x", "y")

def transformRows(iter: Iterator[Row]): Iterator[Row] = iter.map(transformRow)

val newSchema = StructType(df.schema.fields ++ Array(
  StructField("z", IntegerType, false), StructField("v", IntegerType, false)))

sqlContext.createDataFrame(df.rdd.mapPartitions(transformRows), newSchema).show

// +---+----+---+---+
// |  x|   y|  z|  v|
// +---+----+---+---+
// |1.0| 2.0| -1|  1|
// |0.0|-1.0| -1|  1|
// |3.0| 4.0| -1|  1|
// |6.0|-2.3| -1|  1|
// +---+----+---+---+
```

Comment: I like the way how scala code is written :)
Thank you!

Comment: @AzatFazulzyanov More precisely: you like the way **zero323** writes scala (/spark) code!

Comment: v well done with the `newSchema`. Saves me to go reengineer that construct

Comment: How can this be written in Java?

Comment: found answer to my question: use scala.collection.JavaConversions to convert from scala Seq to java List

Comment: @zero323 can you also provide an example to do this with Pyspark? I need an example to add new columns to Row within a mapPartitions.