# scala iterate java hashSet

Tags: java, scala, hashset, loops

I wonder how to idiomatically iterate a `java.util.HashSet` in Scala. Currently, I am using the java iterators in a while loop which does not seem to be great.

Additionally, I wonder if the mutable growable buffer is efficient or if there is a possibility to avoid the creation of unnecessary objects.

```
import java.util

import scala.collection.generic.Growable
import scala.collection.mutable

val javaSet = new util.HashSet[String]()
javaSet.add("first")
javaSet.add("second")

val result: collection.Seq[String] with Growable[String] = mutable.Buffer[String]()
val itr = javaSet.iterator

while (itr.hasNext) {
  result += itr.next
}

result
```

## edit

Would a `stream` be better? [Apache Spark: Effectively using mapPartitions in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42539315/apache-spark-effectively-using-mappartitions-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using a Java `HashSet` apparently, do this first:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
```

This lets you turn Java collections into Scala collections, which are much easier to work with, using `asScala`.

So if you have an instance of `HashSet` called `set`, you can do this:

```
set.asScala.map(value => doSomething(value))
```

Or whatever you want to do like `filter`, `foldLeft`, etc.

FYI, the above example can be syntactically sugared to this:

```
set.asScala.map(doSomething)
```

Comment: I see. But will this actually be efficient? As I need to call this method in the mapPartitions method of a spark job I would want to not create unnecessary objects.

Comment: That shouldn't be your concern. Your concern when running a Spark job should be minimizing network shuffle traffic and tuning garbage collection. Besides, you are spending time looking for solutions to a problem that you haven't proven exists. [Premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming.](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)