# Inserting values in row (Spark - Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to create a row (for any given k) such -

for k =2, graph will be [Row(1,2), Row(3,4)]

for k =3, graph will be [Row(1,2,3), Row(4,5,6), Row(7,8,9)]

I am new to scala and dont know how exactly can I insert values in row like this.

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql.Row    
 var graph = ArrayBuffer[Row]()
    
    val k = 3
    val k2 = k * k
    
    for (a <- 1 to k2) {
        graph += Row(a)
      }
```

Comment: What is `Row`? Where it is defined?

Comment: Sorry its from Spark
>>import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

Comment: I think array would also do instead of row

Comment: Since `Row` provide a `fromSeq` method I would focus on creating a **Seq**. I would recommend you to take a look to the `tabulate` method provided by **Seq**, you do not need any mutability to solve this problem, just two `tabulate` calls.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add columns into org.apache.spark.sql.Row inside of mapPartitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33876155/how-to-add-columns-into-org-apache-spark-sql-row-inside-of-mappartitions)

Answer (score 0):

```
val k = 3
val range = ArrayBuffer.range(1, k*k + 1) 
val rows = range.map(v => Row(v))
val grouped = rows.grouped(k).toBuffer
```